# Changing the new product widget sort order in Magento

Tags: magento, new-operator, product

I'm using Magento for my webshop and my homepage uses a new products widget. I want to change the sort order for the products within the widget.

I searched for hours but I can't figure it out.

Comment: add more details.do you have toolbar in new.phtml. what you want to do with sort order.provide clear and detail information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block for displaying new product is:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/New.php
```

see the function _beforeToHtml()
default sorting is done by start date descending:

```
->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')
```

You can copy this block to code/local and replace it with position or the sort order you want... or extend it with a Magento extension.

You might want to search [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/) to see if there is any module that would fit your needs.